# AWS stop / start make Wordpress unresponsive

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having tests on AWS EC2 and I setup a Wordpress, everything was good.
But few days after I decided to stop and start (not reboot) the server "to see". And indeed it wasn't a bad idea.
My Wordpress became really slow (90% time out).

I found a fix, I drop all tables in mysql server and then the WordPress server is responsive again (and quick). But of course I need to recreate another database. So I think it comes from the database.

The MySQL server is up (service mysqld status) and all the data are in the tables.

I have nothing on ephemeral storage, / is on an EBS.

UPDATE : with firebug the GET request for html/php seems OK but all css and js is aborted (time out 50s)

I may have missed something...
I'm quite lost, any idea ?

Haelle

Comment: I'm not sure what could be going wrong in here. Do the logs on your webserver (Apache?) say anything? You can add scripts to restart mysql and apache on 'Start'. Check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup). Is a cache plugin installed for wordpress? Could something be going wrong over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause :
I noticed that in firebub the CSS and Javascript was loaded from the prior IP (before the stop aws instance).
Indeed AWS change my IP when I stop / start the instance.
But I didn't know that WordPress keep the website IP in the database and use it to load the css and js files.
So I just updated the IP and it was working again.

Fix :
table to update : 
update wp_options 
set option_value = 
where option_name = 'siteurl';